# Как избежать тавтологии?

Tags: тавтология

> "В связи с проводимыми мероприятиями по проведению комплекса работ по
> обеспечению ..."

В составленном письме мне было сделано конструктивное замечание по поводу повторения слов в предложении. Как правильно построить предложение в данном случае?

Comment: В связи с проводимыми мероприятиями по обеспечению...

Answer (score 1):

Варианты:

*"В связи с мероприятиями по проведению комплекса работ по обеспечению ..."*

"В связи с  мероприятиями по  обеспечению ..."

"В связи с  проведением комплекса работ по обеспечению ..."

"В связи с  мероприятиями  комплекса работ по обеспечению ..."

"В связи с  мероприятиями, необходимыми для обеспечения ..." и т.д.